# Temp tables in delphi query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delphi, temp-tables

I am trying to union this into the temp table. Do you see some wrong syntax in here? 
When I'm executing it is not showing any problem, but when I try to refer to this query it says 'invalid table name #Temp_trans_13' ( I am using MSSQL).

```
select * into #temp_trans_13 from (
select 
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste
where
      Jahr = :jahr
and   periode = 12
and   buchungskreis = :bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
union
select
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste
where
      Jahr = :jahr
and   periode = 13
and   buchungskreis = :bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
union
select
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste

where
      Jahr = :jahr 
and   periode = 14
and   buchungskreis = :bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999')t
```

Comment: Does the query work in SSMS?

Comment: I don't think that I have access to it in my work :/. I Can check it only on Fire Dac Explorer and there it shows that params are undefined

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  For me, SSMS 2014 doesn't seem to like the `... (select * from anything)` - it complains about the closing parenthesis)

Comment: @MartynA Well that's the first problem!

Comment: I am pretty new to all of those things, so I am not familiar to all of that stuff (yet!). :P

Comment: @JichałMurek And that's the second problem.

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  Indeed, that's why I added the sql-server tag, hoping it might attract a specialist.

Comment: @JichałMurek the question has nothing to do with Delphi, it's pure SQL. This means you need to install and use SSMS or ADS to try these things. A *temporary* table is temporary - someone has to create it. A table starting with a `#` exists only in the current connection which means *your code* has to create it.

Comment: @JichałMurek You found them. The problem is the missing closing ) at the end. The other is that you can't use the same parameter name over and over.

Comment: Funny thing is that i have been using this ... (select * from anything) on some previous projects and it worked there without problems. This suprises me

Comment: Oh but the project i am writing in delphi. It just uses sql server. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: That subquery seems to be returning the same data from the same table for different criteria combinations. It could be replaced by a *single* query combining all combinations with OR. `UNION` is an expensive operation as it needs to return distinct values.

Comment: @nolaspeaker:  No, it's the closing `)` that SSMS complains about, which I have to say puzzles me because I would expect the construct to work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "someone has to create it".  Well, the query is supposed to create it.  In any case, the OP is using Delphi, which comes with perfectly good db-querying tools built-in so doesn't need SSMS.

Comment: @MartynA if the server complains about missing tables, it means there was an attempt to *use* that table before it was created. Most likely in some code the OP didn't post here. A missing `)` would result in a different error. That query is long enough that it's hard to see what it does - or how repetitive it is

Comment: @MartynA the reason everyone asks `Does it work in SSMS?` first in such questions is to isolate whether is't a programming error or a bad query. If something doesn't  work when executed directly against the database, it won't work in an IDE or at runtime either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:  Well, with the simplified query I've been using `select * into #mytemp from (select * from table1)`, it is the closing `)` that SSMS complains about, not a missing table.  Btw, I am perfectly well aware of your point about SSMS.

Comment: I have reinstated the Delphi tag so that the q doesn't vanish from view for its followers.

Comment: Btw, no-one has asked the obvious question, namely does the Sql inside your `(` ... `)` execute and produce the results you expect.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the entire query could be simplified to :

```
select 
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr
into #temp_trans_13 
from sap_SuSa_liste
where
      Jahr = :jahr
     and   periode in (12,13,14)
     and   buchungskreis = :bkr
     and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
```

`UNION` returns distinct values which means that even if SQL Server's query optimizer was smart enough to avoid executing N queries it would *still* have to sort and group the data to eliminate duplicates.

If duplicate elimination is required, one can add `DISTINCT` to the SELECT clause

**Temporary Tables**

Temporary Tables are temporary. They only exist for the duration of a single connection. Those that have a single `#` prefix are only visible to the connection that created them.

The error `invalid table name #Temp_trans_13` can only be raised when *another* query tries to use that table and can't find it, either because it wasn't created yet or because it was created in a different connection.

To use a temp table from another connection one needs to create a [global temporary table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4031/sql-server-global-temporary-table-visibility/) by using `##` as a prefix.

Comment: I am pretty sure all of those answers would work but somehow its not working in my delphi. My job is to retype whole system from virtual windows xp machine delphi 5 to delphi 10 so maybe some other code might be archaic .

Comment: This has nothing to do with Delphi. Did you try to run your queries *directly* against the database? The error you got means that some *other* query tried to use that table and didn't find it. How did you call the other query? Did you call it in the same connection or a different one? `#temp_trans_13` exists only for the duration of a single connection and is only visible inside that connection

Comment: So. Yes it is connected to the same fdconnection. I called query ' select * from #temp_trans_13'

Comment: Also in fd explorer it doesn't see it

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, I find it helpful to try a query which boils the problem down to its essentials.

Using SSMS 2014, I have a `Table1` which consists of a single `Int` column named `ID`.

If I attempt

```
select * into #mytemp from (select * from table1)
```

I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I get the same error message if I attempt

```
select ID from (select * from table1)
```

However, following the example in section **R. Using a derived table** of the
[TransactSql docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
this query

```
select ID from (select * from table1) as derivedtable
```

the query executes correctly and produces the expected single-column result set.

Further, executing

```
select * into #mytemp from (select * from table1) as derivedtable
```

executes correctly and produces the expected results.

So, it is obviously the `as xxxx` which make the difference between the
`(select ... from ...)` construct not working and working.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problems:

```
declare 
   @bkr varchar(10),
   @jahr int

set @bkr = :bkr
set @jahr = :jahr

select T.* 
into #temp_trans_13 
from     
(
select 
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste
where
      Jahr = @jahr
and   periode = 12
and   buchungskreis = @bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
union
select
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste
where
      Jahr = @jahr
and   periode = 13
and   buchungskreis = @bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
union
select
      periode,
      konto_nr as ktonr,
      konto_kurztext as ktobez,
      soll_periode - haben_periode as SaldoMonat,
      soll_saldo - haben_saldo as SaldoJahr

from
      sap_SuSa_liste

where
      Jahr = @jahr 
and   periode = 14
and   buchungskreis = @bkr
and   konto_nr between '200000' and '999999'
) T
```

Comment: Well, thanks for  a effort but the problem is still there. ;(

Comment: Which problem exactly?

Comment: @JichałMurek what problem and what *exactly* did you try? You *wouldn't* get the error message you posted from *this* query, or any missing `)`. Most likely you get an error from the *next* query that can't find the temporary table

Comment: @JichałMurek You must report the exact problem you are having, exact words, if you want further help with this.

Comment: So. there is a sequence of querries that are reffering to themselves. And they are working correctly apart from my last query which is reffering to one which i have described because it shows an error 'invalid table name blablabla' ;/

Comment: I will edit my answer to that it once again makes the `#temp_trans_13` table.

Comment: Jesus it is really stresfull situation. @PanagiotisKanavos yes this is the problem

Comment: ```Insert into hm_Sap_Fibu_Trans
select
      ktonr,
      ktobez,
      sum(SaldoMonat) as SaldoMonat,
      sum(SaldoJahr) as SaldoJahr
from
      #temp_trans_13 
group by
      ktonr,
      ktobez``` i dont know how to make this code more readable. This is text which is in the last query which is having a problem

Comment: It should. But somehow it is not ;( i can't find it in fire dac and also next query doesnt see it grrr sorry for being so newbie

Comment: @JichałMurek So now you tell us! :-) Make sure the previous step is as my answer above, then the query you gave in the comments just now, will also find the `#temp_trans_13`.